# sending a POST xml request using httperf at a given rate

Tags: http, benchmarking, httperf

i want to send a httperf request to post a list of uri,xml pair at a given rate using httperf.
I tried various optios

eg using --wsesslog option but i am not able to produce the desired output.
can any one know a way how can i achieve it?

Comment: Could use some more information, but essentially you'll want to write a session file containing the data in it to be posted.  The man page has a pretty good example of how to specify the data:  http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/httperf-man-0.9.txt

Comment: Also may want to look out for an issue I just ran into with httperf.. You can only specify one post data format in the file.  Multiples will be ignored, and only the first will get posted continuously.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (waited for long time :P )
Yes you are right the data file is used in this case.